# Create a new Xcode project in an existing Git repo

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have an iOS app I was writing using React Native until I realized React Native wouldn't fit my needs and I'd need to write the app with Xcode. Because my original project is already in a repo on GitHub, I'd like to use my existing Git repo for the new Xcode project.

I'm new to IDEs and a little scared that if I just move the files over something will get messed up and I won't know how to fix it. Is there a more orthodox way to do this? I've googled this and have come up with lots of advice for adding a new Git repo to an existing Xcode project, but not the other way around.

Comment: Just create a new project, close it in Xcode, and drag everything from one folder to the other. But keep the same relative relationship between them (i.e. if Foo is a folder beside Foo.xcodeproj, keep it there). You can use the terminal to `git add` if you need to.

Comment: OK cool, thanks. That seemed like one way I could do it but I wondered if there was another one. Xcode is way too magical for me!

Comment: Don't worry. It's just new to you. It'll become way less magical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply create a new Xcode project and choose to create it in the same folder on your Mac that is the local copy of the repo.

Deselect the option that says "Create Git repository on my Mac".

This will effectively show up in your local repo as a bunch of files that were added—even an empty Xcode project contains several files.

Xcode will just use the existing repo setup that was already there. So naturally the first step after creating the project would be to commit the Xcode project.

(NB. there is no "rule" that a single repo can not house various projects or "things", although in practice you would often create a fresh repo for the new thing instead of throwing everything together in one)